# How can I undo my vote?

Tags: support, downvotes, undo

I accidentally down-voted a question. Can I perform an undo on that vote, without upvoting it?

I don't consider this particular question deserves a downvote, but have no reason (or knowledge) to upvote it either. Is an undo possible?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just click on the downvote button a second time to undo it.  The same applies to upvotes.

Note that votes cannot be undone after a certain amount of time has passed, unless the post is edited.

Comment: Darn, so easy... It confused me, because I didn't knew about the time-trigger. Anyway thanks

Comment: Thanks.  It would make more sense IMHO for a click on the up arrow to also have the effect of undoing the downvote.  A second click on the up arrow would then change it to an upvote.

Comment: Without this post I would have never known this.  I feel like this functionality is not clearly worded any where (at least that i've come across before).

Comment: I downvoted an answer, but after some time I realized I was wrong and would like to undo it. Unfornately it's already 2 hours later and I am not allowed to undo. Clicking upvote also does not work because I've downvoted it.

Comment: I do not have the privilege yet to downvote. But accidentally upvoted a question, but I can't click downvote to undo my upvote. I think although I'm not allowed to downvote, I should be able to undo my own upvote?

Comment: @RoelBalink You don't need to downvote to undo an upvote, for the same reason that you don't need to upvote to undo a downvote, as the question asks about.  You just need to press the button a second time to undo the vote.

Comment: I get message like `you last voted on this answer 39 minutes ago, your vote is now locked unless the post is edited`, this was on iPad though and I don’t think I’ve seen that occur on desktop before. maybe I double clicked the arrow unintentionally and there is a limit to how many vote/undo vote’s you can do.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind locking a vote? Why can not I undo upvote after certain amount of time passed?

Comment: @MoyseyAbramowitz https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked

Comment: I was prevented from undoing an upvote after 60 seconds. Why such a short time limit?

Comment: What is the rationale for locking a vote after only a few minutes? What use case does it solve? Seems more like a hindrance than a help, in my opinion.