# Make text easier: "You last voted on this answer on DATE at TIME (/ x minutes ago). Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Tags: feature-request, voting, locked-votes

Always confused me a bit when reading it, just because it is so brilliantly short:

> You last voted on this answer on DATE at TIME (/ x minutes ago). Your vote is now locked
> in unless this answer is edited.

[image]

I took the time and searched whether there was any meta talk about it. [How can I undo my vote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294938/how-can-i-undo-my-vote) helped me understand "what is going on here". And there is an overview at [How does vote locking work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299937/how-does-vote-locking-work).

Think of a beginner at such meta questions, and of a non-native English speaker, who might be confused in several ways by this very short message, and who will not search for this on meta.

*Possible confusion (you can skip this):*

- whether the vote will be done after the next edit.
- whether nothing will happen at the next edit.
- whether a vot has yet been done in that moment and cannot be changed now
- whether you have to click again on the vote at that moment to revert the vote that was probably not valid.
- whether this reverted vote might perhaps take back the original vote.
- whether this message pops up perhaps also because you had voted the other direction at first.
- whether the future edit of the answer might allow you to upvote twice or downvote twice.
- whether this has anything to do with a need of editing, and whether "editing" means just changing a small typo or needs to be more than that.

Please do not think that this is what someone really thinks about it. It is just the logical puzzles that might come up for no reason.

**That is why I suggest changing this to a longer and easier explanation:**

> You last voted on this answer on DATE at TIME, x minutes ago. Only until x minutes after
> the vote, you can take back your vote by clicking on the same button
> again or even by voting in the other direction. At this moment, your last vote was
> too long ago, it was *locked in*, and you cannot change it now. You can
> well change your vote again as soon as this answer gets edited again. In
> any case, mind that you can never vote the same vote twice.

Or something the like, probably shorter. The main thing is that this message should be easy to understand by **non-native English speakers and beginners**.

It should avoid the word "unless"; "edited" should be just "changed"; and perhaps even "locked in" might be hard to read in this sentence.

On the other hand, the current message is brilliantly short. Which could be a good reason to keep it as it is, since no one wants to read such a long story either. Point of discussion, I still suggest changing the text a bit.

Comment: And pray, how will you fit all that text into the same size of a box? Making the box bigger is not an option IMO. That being said, I think the text is a little confusing and I'm up for a change.

Comment: At least "Your vote cannot be changed" would be clearer than "Your vote is now locked in".

Comment: Far to long to be useful or even helpful. There is no need to provide a full on explanation for something like that.

Comment: *You last voted on this answer on DATE at TIME (/ x minutes ago). You can only change your vote after this answer is edited.*

Comment: Why not just a link in the message to the meta?

Comment: @Scratte not sure about that specific fly-out/ tooltip but in Chrome those won't stay open when I move my mouse into the text bubble. I'll never reach that link to click it.

Comment: @rene I see. That's unfortunate. For me (using Opera) if stays there for 5 seconds. If I want to click something inside it and I'm too slow, I could just click the voting arrow again. Here I managed to copy the content "You last voted on this question 57 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this question is edited." :)

Comment: They can always increase the time the toast message stays on the page or even require the user to dismiss it instead of making it disappear if they put a link in it (though I guess it's not toast at that point).

Comment: Re *"edited" should be just "changed"*: That is a good point. It is also my impression that "edit" is not understood (or is it just because forums *traditionally* never offered the option to change text once submitted, not even the first few minutes?). In `share edit follow close flag` on every question, `edit` could be `change` instead.

Comment: Many people only see the message when they realized after clicking that they had clicked previously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement isn't meant to explain everything; that's what the Help Center is for.  If it's not in there, this is the signal to Stack Exchange to add it in there.

It's also available [over here in the uber-Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/175248).  It's so detail-rich that you would actually not have enough space to fit it in on the little error modal.

Comment: "The statement isn't to explain everything": This is not the problem, the problem is that it confuses. I mean, even if I know exactly what the text should tell me, I am *still* unconciously confused by the "now", and the "edited". I would not say that adding a link to an overview that is so large that you will not even start reading it will help the beginners here. What is needed is a slightly longer and easier text, perhaps after clicking a "More" link, taking um the link idea. And in that second link, there could be the FAQ link that you offered.

Comment: Don't take this question the wrong way, but are you not a native English speaker?  The adverb "now" is [pretty common as a manner of discourse and speech](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/now), and its usage here is spot-on.

Comment: I am not a native speaker, of course, that is why I also see the text in another light. I have never heard of this usage of "now" before, when it actually would fit to say "since then" or "thus" instead. The question is about making the text easier, so that Stack beginners and non-native speakers are not that confused by it.